# How to disable local news texts to iphone

Tags: messages, sms

My iPhone 6 receives text messages of local news stories, from a local news source.

I can't discover how to unsubscribe from these messages. How is it done?

This is my first iOS device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to contact whoever is sending them to you, and request that they stop. Generally replying with the word "STOP" will unsubscribe you.

This is not specific to Apple devices.

Comment: Thanks, figured it was an iOS thing, becuase I've never had a phone that signed me up for text news alerts before.

Comment: I'm assuming you got a new phone number with your new phone? The last owner of the phone number likely signed up for the messages.

Comment: Hadn't occurred to me. Good point.